# Getting 'TypeError: 'str' object is not callable' for python script

Tags: python

When i run this below script, i am getting this error and not able to identify what is it?
can someone help here?

Seeing error in line 14 as below

```
SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
test = db.profiles_data.count_documents({"createdOn": {"$lt": {"ISODate"("2020-12-01T12:00:00.000+0000")}}, "createdOn": {"$gte": {"ISODate"("2020-11-30T11:00:00.000+0000")}}})
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Code:

```
import pymongo
import json
from collections import namedtuple
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def getLogCount():

    uri = "mongodb connection string comes here"
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
    db = client.get_database('profile')

    test = db.profiles_data.count_documents({"createdOn": {"$lt": {"ISODate"("2020-12-01T12:00:00.000+0000")}}, "createdOn": {"$gte": {"ISODate"("2020-11-30T11:00:00.000+0000")}}})
    print("Test Count           : %d" %test)

LogCount = getLogCount()
```

Answer (score 0):

`"ISODate"("2020-12-01T12:00:00.000+0000")`

should probably be

`"ISODate": "2020-12-01T12:00:00.000+0000"`

or possibly

`"ISODate(2020-12-01T12:00:00.000+0000)"`

(both places where `ISODate` appears)